# how to improve image quality for the SEUploader?

Tags: discussion, site-tools

I noticed SEUploader images are not good when copied over to stackexchange forum.

I do not know if this is the effect of latest changes done at stackexchange server or what (we had problem with SEUploader not long ago)

For example, here is an image ([link here to actual file](https://www.12000.org/tmp/04192020/Untitled.png)) which I uploaded using SEUploader "image" button. (the image (PP) button has not worked for me for 
very long time, each time I try it, I hear a loud beep).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I did the same again, but first this code (thanks to Silvia (please see [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106908/discussion-between-silvia-and-nasser) )

```
ClearAll[SETools`SEUploader`Private`uploadButton]
SETools`SEUploader`Private`uploadButton[] := 
  With[{img = 
     SETools`SEUploader`Private`rasterizeSelection1[650*(144/72)]}, 
   If[img === $Failed, Beep[], 
    SETools`SEUploader`Private`uploadWithPreview[img]]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see it is much better. It is same cell in my notebook.

So this shows there is some settings not correct in SEUploader.

---

## Additional Information

(from Silvia's side)

I have Mathematica 12.1 on Windows 10. Here is what I observed. In following screenshot, the upper window is the one corresponding to "Image" button in SEUploader, the lower windows is the one corresponding to "Image (pp)". Without looking into SEUploader's source code, I boldly suspect it might be related to a too small window width of an invisible notebook it used to temporarily hold the image cell.

[image: Image vs. Image (PP)]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106908/discussion-between-silvia-and-nasser).